# Grouping data via LinQ in Powershell

Tags: powershell, linq, group-by

I have an array of data and I need to group them by 2 attributes and then calculate the sum of a third attribute per each group. I want to do this via Linq to be as fast as possible.

This is my demo-code so far:

```
class costs {
    [string] $first;
    [string] $last;
    [int]    $price;
    costs([string]$first, [string]$last, [int] $price){
        $this.first = $first
        $this.last  = $last
        $this.price = $price
    }
}

[costs[]]$costs = @(
    [costs]::new('peter', 'parker', 1),
    [costs]::new('peter', 'parker', 2),
    [costs]::new('paul',  'summer', 3),
    [costs]::new('paul',  'winter', 4),
    [costs]::new('mary',  'winter', 5)
)

# group by full name:
$groupBy = [Func[Object,string]] {$args[0].first + $args[0].last}
$groupResult = [Linq.Enumerable]::GroupBy($costs, $groupBy)

# sum the costs per group:
$selectFunc   = [Func[Object,int]] {$sum=0; foreach($p in $args[0].price){$sum += $p};$sum}
$selectResult = [Linq.Enumerable]::Select($groupResult, $selectFunc)

$selectResult
```

The selectResult shows me the correct sum of the costs for each user.
But I am struggling to get the sum togehter with the two user attributes from initial array.
I am also not sure, if I could combine both Linq-calls in a single one to make it faster.
Any input is more than welcome here (except "why Linq?").

**Update**

Based on the answers I updated the code like this:

```
class costs {
    [string] $first;
    [string] $last;
    [int]    $price;
    costs([string]$first, [string]$last, [int] $price){
        $this.first = $first
        $this.last  = $last
        $this.price = $price
    }
}

[costs[]]$costs = @(
    [costs]::new('peter', 'parker', 1),
    [costs]::new('peter', 'parker', 2),
    [costs]::new('paul',  'summer', 3),
    [costs]::new('paul',  'winter', 4),
    [costs]::new('mary',  'winter', 5)
)
foreach($doubler in 0..15){$costs += $costs}

cls
write-host "processing $($costs.count) elements."

(measure-command {
    # group by full name:
    $groupBy = [Func[Object,string]] {$args[0].first + $args[0].last}
    $groupResult = [Linq.Enumerable]::GroupBy($costs, $groupBy)

    # sum the costs per group:
    $selectFunc = [Func[Object,Object]]{
        $sum=0
        foreach($p in $args[0].price){
            $sum += $p
        }
        foreach($a in $args[0]) {
            [costs]::new($a.first, $a.last, $sum)
            break
        }
    }
    $selectResult = [Linq.Enumerable]::Select($groupResult, $selectFunc)
    $result = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray($selectResult)
}).TotalSeconds

$result

# and for the books the same procedure with a dataTable (slower):

$table = [System.Data.DataTable]::new('table')
[void]$table.Columns.Add('first', [string])
[void]$table.Columns.Add('last',  [string])
[void]$table.Columns.Add('price', [int])
$resultTable = $table.Clone()

# fill table with above test-data:
foreach($c in $costs){
    $null = $table.rows.Add($c.first, $c.last, $c.price)
}

(measure-command {
    $groupBy = [Func[System.Data.DataRow,string]] {$args[0].first + $args[0].last}
    $groupResult = [Linq.Enumerable]::GroupBy([System.Data.DataRow[]]$table.Rows, $groupBy)

    # sum the costs per group:
    $selectFunc = [Func[object,System.Data.DataRow]]{
        $sum=0
        foreach($p in $args[0].price){
            $sum += $p
        }
        foreach($a in $args[0]) {
            $resultTable.rows.Add($a.first, $a.last, $sum)
            break
        }
    }
    $selectResult = [Linq.Enumerable]::Select($groupResult, $selectFunc)
    $null = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToList($selectResult)
}).TotalSeconds
$resultTable
```

The runtime for over 300000 elements is around 2.5 seconds. Not that bad. Till now I could not find a faster approach without switching to embedded C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `$selectFunc` definition to return `[psobject]` or `[object]` instead, then create the resulting object from the existing grouped value:

```
$selectFunc   = [Func[Object,psobject]]{
    $sum=0
    foreach($p in $args[0].price){
      $sum += $p
    }

    # Output new object with first+last based on input object + sum
    $args[0] |Select first,last,@{Name='sum';Expression={$sum}} -First 1
}
```

---

> I want to do this via Linq to be as fast as possible.

I'd strongly suggest you actually *test* whether this is faster than using, say `Group-Object`, or a simple hashtable for the calculations - a lot of the overhead that makes PowerShell slow (notably parameter binding), will still apply to your code, so the difference might not be significant - but the *readability* of your script might suffer significantly.

My personal preference would be to just use the `Group-Object` cmdlet:

```
$costs |Group-Object first,last |ForEach-Object {
  $sum = ($_.Group |Measure price -Sum).Sum
  $_.Group |Select -Property first,last,@{N='Sum';E={$sum}} -First 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Of course I will double-check if the result is faster than the regular grouping-function. I rememer I did a couple of performance-tests with Linq in Powerwhell in the past and it turns out, that a manual foreach-logic was faster at the end.

Comment: @Carsten Fixed :) I also added a simple `Group-Object` example you can compare with. To measure the total execution speed of each approach, generate a larger set of test data and compare output from `Measure-Command`. For deeper profiling, take a look at [PSProfiler](https://github.com/IISResetMe/PSProfiler)